# Buttons on stackexchange.com look weird on Internet Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com, internet-explorer-11

When using Chrome, Firefox or IE9 everything is OK.

However, using IE10 or IE11, some buttons looks like this:

> [image]

[Link to page with those buttons](https://stackexchange.com/filters/2540) - browse with IE10 or IE11 and log in to reproduce.

On other sites I couldn't see this type of buttons.

This also happens in [Stack Exchange portal](http://www.stackexchange.com):

> [image]

Not very nice, is it?

Comment: Haha I give up... IE10's dev tools are garbage... It's discarding the rule for *some* reason, but it should be supported.

Comment: @animuson - My css-fu is weak, but according to the [w3c recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-images-20120417/#linear-gradients), you need to prefix `top` with `to`, e.g. `linear-gradient(to top ...`

Comment: @animuson jsfiddle is crashing my IE10 since they moved to the cloud a while ago (before that it simply didn't work in IE at all), if your IE10 is tougher [here's a fiddle to mess with](http://jsfiddle.net/sHR99/).

Comment: @chuex might be on to something, feel free to check in the fiddle!

Comment: *It works in Chrome and IE9* Well, we have a solution than, right?

Comment: This is actually by design. Internet Explorer was designed specifically to render any feature deemed useful in a way so as to break its functionality.

Comment: [Looks like IE10 needs an `-ms-` prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957320/css3-linear-gradient-on-ie10)...anyone else who thinks those prefixes are a stupid idea?

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby nice find, you might have saved the dev who will (hopefully) handle this couple of expansive minutes. And yeah, no doubt those ego wars are totally stupid. :-)

Comment: -1 using Internet explorer.

Comment: @Cole only my sock puppets and to test stuff. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd what?

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Sha's comment is obviously a joke; see [definition for sock puppet here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) (you have to scroll down a bit).

Comment: @chuex I know what a sick puppet is, but I don't understand his comment.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - There's not really much to it. You wrote: "-1 [for] using IE", to which he replied "[I only use IE] for my sock puppets and...".

Comment: @chuex ok. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad default gradient parameter there (was matching the ones for the browser prefixes, which I guess the spec changed on them).

This has been built out and fixes the issue.

Comment: Awesome! Did you happen to verify it's not breaking IE9?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - 9... 2 versions behind... cosmetic issue... blah blah blah... you know what I mean

Answer (score 6):

From the [Microsoft IE 10 Gradient Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673532(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The basic linear gradient syntax is as follows:

```
linear-gradient([ [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ] , ...)
```

The first parameter is either 'angle' or 'side-or-corner'. In this case we are using 'side-or-corner'. So the resulting first parameter is

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, ...
```

**Edit** You will notice that the parameter is `to bottom`, and not `to top`.

---

To demonstrate let's use the following LEGACY Fire Fox CSS as the standard or expected result. It is based on the OP's JS Fiddle. It is simply a div with a black border; the linear gradient is orange at the top and white at the bottom:

Html:

```
<div class="btn">Stack Overflow rulz</div>
```

FF Legacy CSS:

```
.btn {
    height: 100px; border: 2px solid;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fba00c,#ffffff);
}
```

FF Legacy Result:

[image: linear-gradient-ff-legacy]

[FF Legacy Gradient at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Sgh/1/)

---

And finally, here is the CSS for IE 10. This, by the way, follows the [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-images-20120417/#linear-gradients). It seems to work in the latest FF and Chrome as well.

Css:

```
.btn {
    height: 100px; border: 2px solid;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fba00c,#ffffff);
}
```

Result in IE 10:

[image: linear-gradient-w3c]

[W3C Gradient at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84gJq/1/)

Comment: I felt a little dirty typing this up, since it feels like an answer that should be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Trying to get hired as a dev for Stack Exchange, aren't you? :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - The thought has occurred to me, but I'm afraid then SE would lose its fun factor for me. In other words I'd have to treat my SE experience as "a job", as opposed to "a game".

Comment: Sorry for not giving the full bounty, still hoping for official response. You'll get half the bounty though and well deserve it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - No worries. As the person that offered the bounty, that is your right. In any case, I can always add a picture of a croissant to get more points :)

Comment: But make it a gradient croissant! ;)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to take a small portion of the background you want to use and then attach it as a scaled image. For example:

1. Use gradient. For example:

      `background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0511 0%,#2600ff 100%)`


   NOTE: Example CSS works in Google Chrome.

   Take a snapshot of a portion of the background and save it somewhere in you're project

   Insert new CSS-rule:

      `background: url('/Images/png/gradient.png') center center fixed;

      background-size: 100% 100%;`

   And after this you have an working background-gradient ( though it is static )